# C#, JSON: Join two array to use JSON

Tags: c#, json

Can you help me to resolve this proplem. I will use JSON with Name and Description and want to merge two array.

```
var listCateogries = categories.Select(x => new
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Description = x.Description
});
var listProducts = products.Select(x => new
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Description = x.Details
});
var data = listCateogries + listProducts;
```

Thanks you very much.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's not arrays. Please learn the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var data = listCateogries.Concat(listProducts);
```